# Starting thread while running flask with debug

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

When I try to start a thread in the same process as a flask app is running, two threads are started. So "once" will be printed twice.

```
from threading import Timer
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True
))

def once():
  print("once")

t = Timer(1, once, ())
t.start()
app.run()
```

This only happens when DEBUG is true.
Anyone have any idea how to prevent this from happening when debugging?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Werkzeug's reloading support has to fork to be able to reload the module correctly. As such your module is imported twice at least; more if you altered the module and it is reloaded.

You can switch this off the reloader with `use_reloader=False`:

```
app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

or you can start your thread in a [`@app.before_first_request` decorated function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request):

```
t = Timer(1, once, ())

@app.before_first_request
def start_thread():
    t.start()
```

The `start_thread` function is now only executed when the first request comes in, not when importing.